# Decrypting possibly compromised Veracrypt hard drive

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, system-compromise

I have a Veracrypt encrypted hard drive, a system drive encryption with the operating system.

The laptop is possibly compromised, which is why I can't decrypt it directly on the laptop. I don't know of a way to confirm or deny if there's an evil maid attack.

I need to know if taking the hard drive out of the laptop, connecting it to another machine and decrypting it there would cause a security risk.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, because you're connecting to the machine meaning that the machine is mounting the drive. If possible maybe use a virtual environment to access it while not allowing the virtual environment to access your files. Even then there are ways around virtual environments. Your best bet is to use a device you only plan on using once unless you're 100 percent certain that you have a controlled environment for such activity and that nothing else can be compromised.

Comment: If the concern is an evil maid attack, how is a virtual environment supposed to help? If simply plugging it in will create a problem, then there will be a problem regardless. If plugging it in will not cause a problem, then your advice doesn't make sense. Either way you slice it, it seems as if this answer contradicts its own threat assessment. Simply mounting the drive doesn't create a problem. Executing whats on the file system or the firmware is what will cause the problem.